# How to add dynamic rows to a table on C#

Tags: c#, jquery

Hi
i have a table and i want to add dynamic rows to that through C# ... how can i do this.... advance thanks

Comment: Hmm. You're not giving much of information here.

Comment: Can you clarify if you mean in the code behind during the page request or in the browser once the page has been rendered? The jQuery tag confuses the issue.

Comment: yes... html table, I want to add values on a button click server event

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add new rows in html table via javascript

```
<asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Check" OnClientClick="javascript:return AddRow();"/>



<script type="text/javascript" >
           var mytable = document.getElementById('mytableID');
           function AddRow() {
               var row = document.createElement('tr');
               mytable.appendChild(row);
               return false;
           }
       </script>
```

Comment: values means? did you mean text in cells?

Comment: Yes..  i want to add form elements in to that table  while saving

Comment: @Nithesh then you should add rows at .cs side and your table should also runat="server"

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear but m giving link so that it will save your time

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/17172-adding-dynamic-row-datagrid.aspx
Come back with little more detail so that u get the answer in no time ,,
Thank